# Why is an identical Mocha test failing after the first one?

Tags: javascript, testing, coffeescript, bind, mocha.js

I have a class `MyClass` that accepts objects to attach to it as methods. These methods call `MyClass.push` to add data to the object's internal `@_list` array. The second of two identical test cases fails, but I don't understand why:

```
chai = require "chai"
chai.should()

obj =
  name: 'foo'
  f: ->
    for i in [1..5]
      @push "Element #{i}"


class MyClass
  constructor: (@options) ->
    @methods = {}
    @_list = []

    if 'attach' of @options
      @attach @options.attach

  push: (m) ->
    @_list.push m

  list: ->
    @_list

  method: (v) ->
    @methods[v].f

  run: (options) ->
    @method('foo')()

  attach: (o) ->
    @methods[o.name] = o
    @methods[o.name].f = o.f.bind(@)

describe 'MyClass', ->
  it 'list should have five elements', ->
    v = new MyClass attach: obj
    v.run()
    v.list().length.should.equal 5
  it 'list should have five elements (#2)', ->
    v = new MyClass attach: obj
    v.run()
    v.list().length.should.equal 5
```

I believe it has something to do with the function binding going, because when I replace the second `v = new MyClass attach: obj` with:

```
v = new MyClass attach:
  name: 'foo'
  f: ->
    for i in [1..5]
      @push "Element #{i}"
```

both tests pass. But I don't understand the behavior, as I thought `.bind()` creates copy of the function. So what's going on here, and how do I get both tests to run independently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript (and thus coffeescript) objects are *pass by reference* . When you start the second test, your `obj` object has changed since you've modified its `f` attribute by doing:

`@methods[o.name].f = o.f.bind(@)`

You can pass a copy of it instead to avoid this.

Comment: I feel that I should understand this, but I don't (although I'm trying!). The 5 elements are set on `v`, not `obj`. I want to keep the array internal to each object (`v`), but `obj` (which contains the function) needs to be able to be shared among different instances of `MyClass`. I'm assuming here that @push refers to the `v` that `obj` is attached to. Am I making sense?

Comment: @user2010963 since `obj` is passed by reference, when you bind `o.f` to the first object by doing `@methods[o.name].f = o.f.bind(@)` you're changing obj. Here is your code corrected http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JlGyq . Also, I apologize, my initial answer was wrong.